# Recursion - Python - Why print(Foo) show something different than print(FunctionReturningFoo())

Tags: python, recursion

Why print(foo) show something different than print(functionreturningthesame())

Look at the output, printing the array in the function show the correct answer, but print the function's return does not. I may be confused with the recursion iteration...

```
def AreNotOpposite(a,b):
  if a == "NORTH" and b == "SOUTH":
    return False
  if a == "SOUTH" and b == "NORTH":
    return False
  if a == "WEST" and b == "EAST":
    return False
  if a == "EAST" and b == "WEST":
    return False
  return True

def canBeBetter(arr):
  for i in range(len(arr)-1):
    if not AreNotOpposite(arr[i],arr[i+1]):
      return True
  return False

def dirReduc(arr):
  re = []
  avoid = -1
  for i in range(len(arr)):
    if avoid == i:
      continue
    if i+1 == len(arr):
      re.append(arr[i])
    elif AreNotOpposite(arr[i],arr[i+1]):
      re.append(arr[i])
    else: #do not append neither the nextone
      avoid = i+1
  if canBeBetter(re):  #can reduce more?
    dirReduc(re)
  else:
    print(re)
    return re

print (dirReduc(['NORTH', 'WEST', 'EAST','SOUTH', 'NORTH','SOUTH','EAST','NORTH']))
```

output:

```
['EAST', 'NORTH']
None
```

Comment: The `if canBeBetter(re):` clause doesn't return anything, but the recursive call inside it `dirReduc(re)` might then call `print`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the result of your recursive call (otherwise your function will hit the end of your logic and simply return `None`):

```
if canBeBetter(re):  #can reduce more?
  return dirReduc(re)
else:
  print(re)
  return re
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted something like this

```
  if canBeBetter(re):  #can reduce more?
    return dirReduc(re)
  else:
    return re
```

Comment: `dirReduc` does not modify its argument, so the recursive call will do nothing other than printing its own result.

Answer (score 0):

**When in Rome...**

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding mutations like `re.append (...)`, reassignment as in the case of `avoid`, and other side effects like `print`. It also means avoiding `for` which is the imperative construct for looping. Recursion is how we loop in functional style, so let's use functional style.

To solve this problem, we're going to treat the input as a queue, `q`, and the output will be constructed using a stack, `s`.

1. If the queue (input) is empty, the stack (output) is fully constructed. Return the reversed stack.
2. *(inductive: `q` is not empty)*

   If the stack is empty, push the first item from the queue onto the stack. Recur.
3. *(inductive: `q` is not empty, `s` is not empty)*

   We have at least one element on each. If the first element of each are `opposite`, drop them. Recur.
4. *(inductive: `q` is not empty, `s` is not empty, elements are not `opposite`)*

   Push the element from the queue onto the stack. Recur.

Here's how we write that in Python -

```
def dir (q, s = []):
  if not q:                   # 1
    return s[::-1]
  elif not s:                 # 2
    return dir \
      ( q[1:]
      , [q[0]] + s
      )
  elif opposite (s[0], q[0]): # 3
    return dir \
      ( q[1:]
      , s[1:]
      )
  else:                       # 4
    return dir \
      ( q[1:]
      , [q[0]] + s
      )
```

We can define `opposite` as -

```
def opposite (a, b, flipped = False):
  if a == "NORTH" and b == "SOUTH":
    return True
  elif a == "EAST" and b == "WEST":
    return True
  elif flipped:
    return False
  else:
    return opposite (b, a, True)
```

Testing it -

```
print (dir (['NORTH', 'WEST', 'EAST','SOUTH', 'NORTH','SOUTH','EAST','NORTH']))
# ['EAST', 'NORTH']
```

---

**Improving consistency and readability**

Python uses a `[...]` syntax for accessing elements of an array but I do think they hurt readability. Consider these helpers -

```
def first (xs = []):
  return xs[0]

def rest (xs = []):
  return xs[1:]

def reverse (xs = []):
  return xs[::-1]
```

Our program's readability is greatly improved thanks to consistent application of functional style -

```
def dir (q, s = []):
  if not q:
    return reverse(s)
  elif not s:
    return dir \
      ( rest(q)
      , [first(q)] + s
      )
  elif opposite (first(s), first(q)):
    return dir \
      ( rest(q)
      , rest(s)
      )
  else:
    return dir \
      ( rest(q)
      , [first(q)] + s
      )
```

Lastly, the `[...] + ...` uses an infix `+` operator which is also a style inconsistency. Functional style is about functions, so instead of making syntax soup to prepend to our lists, we'll use a function -

```
def push (x, xs = []): # immutable push
  return [ x ] + xs

def dir (q, s = []):
  if not q:
    return reverse(s)
  elif not s:
    return dir \
      ( rest(q)
      , push(first(q), s)
      )
  elif opposite (first(s), first(q)):
    return dir \
      ( rest(q)
      , rest(s)
      )
  else:
    return dir \
      ( rest(q)
      , push(first(q), s)
      )
```

View this program and verify the results in your own browser at: [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SnoopyThoseRuntimelibrary)

Comment: Note this program also avoids messy things like `if not AreNotOpposite` and nested `for` loops. A simple chain of logical conditions removes the need for double negation or nested loops.